# Getting max record from vertical table and all verticals

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have one table called jobs.  Each job gets posted to a certain site so a vertical record is created with the posted date and the site it was posted to.

Here's a basic example of my data

**Jobs:**

- `jobid`.
- `positiontitle`.

**Posted:**

- `dateposted`.
- `active`.
- `jobid`.
- `sitename`.

So I need three pieces of this data in my result set.  The position title, the max dateposted and the list of all the sitenames from the Posted table where active is true.  Does anyone know how I could do this in linq to sql with one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might do the trick.

the object with result like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string positiontitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime? maxDatePosted { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> SiteNames { get; set; }
}
```

The `datetime` needs to be of a `nullable datetime` for it to work. Then the queries like this:

```
var result=(
        from jobs in db.Jobs
        select new MyObject()
        {
            positiontitle=jobs.positiontitle,
            maxDatePosted=db.Posted
                            .Where(p =>p.jobid==jobs.jobid)
                            .Max(p =>p.dateposted),
            SiteNames=db.Posted
                        .Where (p =>p.jobid==jobs.jobid && p.active==true)
                        .Select (p =>p.siteName)
        }
    ).ToList();
```

If you want the max dateposted for the active ones as well. Then something like this:

```
var result=(
        from jobs in db.Jobs
        select new MyObject()
        {
            positiontitle=jobs.positiontitle,
            maxDatePosted=db.Posted
                            .Where(p =>p.jobid==jobs.jobid && p.active==true)
                            .Max(p =>p.dateposted),
            SiteNames=db.Posted
                        .Where (p =>p.jobid==jobs.jobid && p.active==true)
                        .Select (p =>p.siteName)
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Where db is the linq database context

Comment: Thank you very much.  One more question though.  Sometimes there are jobs that have not been posted, so the maxDatePosted field is null.  When I run your example in the Linqpad program I get the following error - "The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.DateTime which is a non-nullable value type."  When I run the generated sql I see that it's the maxDatePosted that's null.  Any idea how to set up that field as a nullable datetime in your example?  Thanks again!